# CSS Div border shows up even if hidden

Tags: css, border

I'm currently trying to reproduce a candle effect on a webpage.
Here's the result : https://jsfiddle.net/Zenoo0/z9nejmn3/

**HTML**

```
<div id="light"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#light {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 52px 52px rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 52px 52px rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 0 52px 52px rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.5);
    animation-name: lightFlicker;
    animation-duration:3ms;
    animation-delay:200ms;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

As you can see, my background light still has a little border, even though I previously set it to none.
I can't seem to figure out how to remove it.

Thanks.

Comment: My guess is that this is multiplicating opacities of the background and box-shadow.

Comment: You can play around with radial gradients

Answer (score 3, accepted):

added to `#light` css `filter: blur(4px);`

Comment: I added a `filter: blur(10px);` since 4px wasn't enough, but it works, thanks. Any idea why it behaves like this?

Comment: @user3660134 rendering of shadows is an amazing thing. extremely unstable